# Use more complex where clauses in Scout

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, laravel-scout

I am a happy user of Laravel Scout.

Now I'd like to extend my search:

```
        $data
            = new UserOverviewResourceCollection(User::search($searchphrase)
            ->currentStatus('active')->orderBy('lastname', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('firstname', 'asc')
            ->paginate(config('pagination.length')));
```

currentStatus comes from https://github.com/spatie/laravel-model-status .

Now I am getting a response, that currentStatus is not supported. I thought I could be a good idea to filter the result of User::search after it has been returned from scout?

Another idea: I'd like to add more complex where clauses:

```
->where([
                [
                    'starts_on',
                    '<',
                    Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                ],
                [
                    'ends_on',
                    '>',
                    Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                ],
            ])
```

Maybe you got a better idea?

Answer (score 3):

I really need similar functionality as well but I'm afraid it's not possible at the moment (Laravel 8)

According to the docs; `Laravel\Scout\Builder` (which is what `search()` returns) only has a really basic implementation of the `where` method an can only handle exactly 2 arguments.
Here is the code from the scout package:

```
/**
 * Add a constraint to the search query.
 *
 * @param  string  $field
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return $this
 */
public function where($field, $value)
{
    $this->wheres[$field] = $value;

    return $this;
}
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scout#where-clauses

Putting the `search()` behind all regular eloquent builder methods won't work either since `search` will only be a static function of the model.

Hopefully this will be improved in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Builder and add `currentStatus` method to store required status in builder. See example
https://github.com/matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch/issues/47#issuecomment-526287359

Then you need implement your own engine and build query using builder there.
Here is example for ElasticSearch engine
https://github.com/matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch/blob/06c90914668942b23ffaff7d58af5b9db1901fb1/src/Engines/ElasticSearchEngine.php#L135

Answer (score 0):

I first stumbled upon your question when I was having the same problem a couple of days ago, which is when i decided to build my own solution.
I created a laravel scout fork, and added the following features :

- An array of arrays can be passed as a parameter : where([['id', '>', 5],['id', '<', 10]]).
- Any operator supported by the Eloquent Builder is now supported as well : '=', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '!=', etc.
- Clauses containing the operator like so : where('id', '>', 5).
- All changes are fully backward compatible, If no operator is passed as a parameter, it will be assumed that the desired operator is '='

Inside your laravel project, scout is found in : vendor/laravel/
Replace the scout directory by the cloned repository, and you will be able to use the complex where clause normally.

You can find the repository here : https://github.com/alibaddd/scout

Answer (score -1):

Well rewriting it as this should work.

```
 $data
            = new UserOverviewResourceCollection(User::search($searchphrase)
            ->where('starts_on','<',now())
            ->orderBy('lastname', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('firstname', 'asc')
            ->paginate(config('pagination.length')));
```

Notice that `now()` is just a global helper function returning current moment Carbon instance. It's just shorter to write, no other reason for using it.

And if you want [grouped](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#parameter-grouping) `where` queries you do it like this:

```
 $data
            = new UserOverviewResourceCollection(User::search($searchphrase)
            ->where(function($q) {
               $q->where('starts_on','<',now())->where('ends_on','>',now())
            })
            ->orderBy('lastname', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('firstname', 'asc')
            ->paginate(config('pagination.length')));
```

And then you should be able to export this to the `UserOverviewResourceCollection` as a [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#local-scopes), for example:

```
public function scopeActive($q) {
    return $q->where('starts_on','<',now())->where('ends_on','>',now())
}
```

and then you can use something like this:

```
 $data
            = new UserOverviewResourceCollection(User::search($searchphrase)
            ->active()
            ->orderBy('lastname', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('firstname', 'asc')
```

I've written this from my head so there might be typos.

Comment: Hm, the scope does not work, actually (`Method Laravel\\Scout\\Builder::active does not exist`).  Unfortunately the grouped where does not work, too (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scout#where-clauses) -> `Too few arguments to function Laravel\\Scout\\Builder::where(), 1 passed in .. line 91 and exactly 2 expected`

Comment: Let's go one step at a time. Does the first chunk of code works? If it doesn't, can you remove the `->where('starts_on','<',now())` part and verify that it works then?

Comment: Alright... No, the first chunk does not work:


    "message": "Invalid syntax for numeric condition:starts_on=<",
    "exception": "AlgoliaSearch\\AlgoliaException",
    "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/algolia/algoliasearch-client-php/src/AlgoliaSearch/Client.php",

If I remove the `where` clause it works.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scout#where-clauses Seems complex (whatever that means) queries are not allowed so that could be reason why it's not working. As a long shot, you might try putting the `where` query before the `search()` otherwise you'll probably have to index the `starts_on` and `ends_on` fields in Algolia and then do the query there through their API.

Another, ugly, workaround might be to get the ID's from Algolia and then re-do the query on your database using the `whereIn('id',$arrayOfIDsFromAlgolia)` but there should be a way to do it in Algolia.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $data
        = new UserOverviewResourceCollection(User::search($searchphrase)
        ->currentStatus('active')->orderBy('lastname', 'asc')
        ->where(function($q){
            $query->where('starts_on', '<',Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
            $query->where('ends_on', '>',Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
         })
        ->orderBy('firstname', 'asc')
        ->paginate(config('pagination.length')));
```

Try this code. This will satisfy your complex where condition

Comment: Hi and thank you.

Unfortunately it still returns `Method Laravel\\Scout\\Builder::currentStatus does not exist.`

Comment: Hi, currentStatus functin is written in you question itself.

please remove "->currentStatus('active')" and try.

Comment: Yes, it's written there for a good reason - I need it ;-)

`currentStatus` comes from currentStatus comes from https://github.com/spatie/laravel-model-status as i wrote on my initial question :-)